# extract lmg from calc.relimp in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the lmg information from the results i'm getting from calc.relimp found in the relaimpo package.

when i view my results i see

```
Response variable: DS[, 2] 
Total response variance: 107.5848 
Analysis based on 21985 observations 

3 Regressors: 
DS[, 33] DS[, 18] DS[, 23] 
Proportion of variance explained by model: 1.39%
Metrics are not normalized (rela=FALSE). 

Relative importance metrics: 

                 lmg
DS[, 33] 0.007041436
DS[, 18] 0.001038892
DS[, 23] 0.005823708

Average coefficients for different model sizes: 

                 1X        2Xs        3Xs
DS[, 33] -1.9229313 -2.3138967 -2.4784731
DS[, 18] -0.9155606 -0.8011497 -0.6107294
DS[, 23]  1.3592192  2.0488534  2.3525688
```

i would ideally like to extract 33 0.00704, 18 0.00103, 23 0.00582 so i can run more analysis on the lmg values.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the structure of your object calculated with `calc.relimp()` function using function `list()`.

`lmg` values are stored in list element with the same name and can selected as `object@lmg`.

Here is example using data from this package

```
library(relaimpo)
data(swiss)
ll<-calc.relimp(swiss)
str(ll)
Formal class 'relimplm' [package "relaimpo"] with 36 slots
  ..@ var.y      : num 156
  ..@ R2         : num 0.707
  ..@ R2.decomp  : num 0.707
  ..@ lmg        : Named num [1:5] 0.0571 0.1712 0.2601 0.1056 0.1128
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Agriculture" "Examination" "Education" "Catholic" ...
  .....
  ..@ car.diff   : num(0) 
  ..@ namen      : chr [1:6] "Fertility" "Agriculture" "Examination" "Education" ...
  ..@ nobs       : int 47
  ..@ ave.coeffs : num [1:5, 1:5] 0.194 -1.011 -0.862 0.139 1.786 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "Agriculture" "Examination" "Education" "Catholic" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1X" "2Xs" "3Xs" "4Xs" ...
  ....

ll@lmg
 Agriculture      Examination        Education         Catholic Infant.Mortality 
  0.05709122       0.17117303       0.26013468       0.10557015       0.11276592
```

Answer (score 1):

relaimpo also caters for users who are used to lists and the $ extractor, i.e. the following would also work:

```
library(relaimpo)
ll <- calc.relimp(swiss)
ll$lmg ## instead of ll@lmg
```